# Appending to section goes outside the section

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Okay so basically I have a chat app I made and it appends a paragraph to the chat class which is inside a div which the class chat is a section but when I make enough messages it would put the messages outside the section as in like the background color would only show for a certain amount of messages then just be normal so like the height of it is broken for some reason and I can't figure out how to fix that.

[image: picture of it breaking]

```js
$('.chat').append('<p id="' + Math.random() + '"><strong style=color:' +
  data.color + '> ' + data.user + '</strong> <span style=color:"black">' +
  data.message + '</span></p>');
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

html {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Mukta Malar', Arial;
  /*font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans, sans-serif;*/
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.user-count {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.chat {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 165px);
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: 90%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /*this is for the msgs */
}

.adminTools {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 165px);
  background: white;
  opacity: 90%;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.chat p {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

input[type=color],
button {
  /*input alonwas here too*/
  width: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ddd;
}

@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
  .chat {
    height: 300px;
    /* height: calc(100vh - 140px);*/
  }
  input {
    width: calc(100% - 160px);
  }
  button {
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
  }
}

.scroller {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; */
}

.scroller section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

div {
  overflow: auto;
}

#colorPicker {
  width: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.adminTitle {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden !Important
}

input[type=color] {
  width: 70px !important;
  height: 70px !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type=color]::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 50%;
  border-color: white;
}

.userDiv {
  position: fixed;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
}


/*remove this if it breaks*/

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.inp {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inp .label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 500;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.inp .focus-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
}

.inp input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 16px 12px 0 12px;
  height: 56px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
}

.inp input:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.inp input:not(:-moz-placeholder-shown)+.label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translate3d(0, -12px, 0) scale(0.75);
}

.inp input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder)+.label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translate3d(0, -12px, 0) scale(0.75);
}

.inp input:not(:placeholder-shown)+.label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translate3d(0, -12px, 0) scale(0.75);
}

.inp input:focus {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 #0077FF;
}

.inp input:focus+.label {
  color: #0077FF;
  transform: translate3d(0, -12px, 0) scale(0.75);
}

.inp input:focus+.label+.focus-bg {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4c6e87;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px -2px rgba(60, 83, 199, 0.5);
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.btn.ripple {
  background-position: center;
  transition: background 0.8s;
}

.btn.ripple:hover {
  background: #3f5a6e radial-gradient(circle, transparent 1%, #3f5a6e 1%) 50%/16000%;
}

.btn.ripple:active {
  background-color: #3f5a6e;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s, transform 0.2s;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Msged</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <main>
    <header>
      <center>
        <h1 class="user-count">Online: 0</h1>
      </center>
    </header>
    <!-- <article class="scroller"> -->
    <div id="maindiv1">
      <!-- style="height:400px;"> -->
      <section class="chat"></section>
      <!--  </article> -->
    </div>
    <form>
      <label for="inp" class="inp">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Message #main" />

      <!--  <input type="text" style="border-radius: 25px; border: 1px inline black;" placeholder="Say something" /> -->
          
        </label>
      <!--  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename"> -->

      <button class="btn ripple">Send</button>


    </form>

  </main>

  <main>
    <header>
      <form>
        <h1 id="colorPicker">
        </h1>
        <h1 id="userChecker">
        </h1>
        <!--      <button id="colorBtn">Change Colour</button> -->
      </form>
    </header>
  </main>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cookie_js@1.2.2/cookie.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.slim.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: .chat <section> has fixed height from CSS, so the more <p>s you append, they will overflow the section.

Comment: I don't see where I should fix that @cheesyMan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `overflow: auto;` to `.chat` in the css-file lets the section scroll and keep its background.